# Obtener Path de productos de una orden WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Estoy intentando crear un query para obtener las imagenes de los articulos vendidos en woocommerce

actualmente tengo las siguientes consultas

```
SELECT * FROM `wpsz_posts` where id = '13577'

SELECT * FROM `wpsz_postmeta` where post_id = '13577'
```

Esto me proporciona info del pedido, googleando encontre que se supone que wpsz_postmeta deberia tener _wp_attached_file

solo algunos tienes ese campo, entonces no entiendo o no encuentro donde encuentro las imagenes de los articulos en woocommerce

si hago esta consulta

```
SELECT * FROM `wpsz_postmeta` WHERE meta_key IN ('_wp_attached_file')
```

si aparecen algunas imagenes pero hice un pedido de prueba y mi pedido no carga este campo en esta tabla de postmeta,

porque aveces carga y aveces no?, en el caso de que no lo carge lo carga en otro lado?, estoy bastante perdido

Comment: Prueba con la meta key **`_thumbnail_id`**

Comment: No todos los "postmeta" tienen esta key, eso es lo que no entiendo porque algunos si lo guardan y otras simplemente lo ignora